# Call PowerShell script from Word macro

Tags: microsoft-word, powershell, vba, macros

I'm trying to call a PowerShell script from a macro in Word.

```
Sub Connect_01()
  Dim x As Variant
  x = Shell(powershell -command "& { iwr ftp://USER:PASSWORD@files.000webhost.com/TEST -OutFile C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\TEST }" )
End Sub
```

I'm trying to run the script but it show me an error. Is there any way to execute it?

I get a compiler error: Syntax error

As I don't have much experience with VBA, and none with the Shell() command, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to begin by narrowing the source of the problem: replace the PowerShell command with something else in the Shell line. With this error I'm guessing most of the problem is with your VBA and has little to do with your PS code.

Comment: If you were just issuing your command on the Command line, what would it look like exactly? Are any of the items in the command "variables" ? Perhaps you can modify your question. As a hint, the entire command needs to a string  [at the moment that means your code probably needs to start Shell("powershell -command ] and for VBA, doublequotaiton marks inside strings need to be doubled up, so, e.g. "this is a string with a "" (double quotation mark) in it"

Comment: yokki,Thank you very much for responding, but honestly I just want this code to run in macro: https://i.imgur.com/KDOFd2f.png